# Very infrequent values in embedding layers

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, word-embeddings, categorical-data

I have a categorical input that is very imbalanced. 90% of the values are either A or B and frequencies for C, D, E, F, etc are as little as 1.

I am using an embedding layer for this input and the result is not too bad.

Does such small frequency cause any instability or troubles for the neural network model?